# What is the right algorithm to solve this problem?

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, dependency-management, puzzles

The problem is - 
We have a series of boxes (A, B, C, D, ...). 
Each box contains bricks of different colours. For eg.

```
Box A - red, blue
Box B - blue, red, green

... and so on...
```

and there are multiple versions of each of the boxes -

```
Box A1 - red, blue
Box A2 - green, red, yellow
...

Box B1 - blue, red, green
Box B2 - blue, red

... and so on ...
```

The idea is to choose one of the versions of each of the boxes, such the total number of unique bricks is minimum. For eg. in this example -

```
Box A1 + Box B1 = blue, red, green (3 unique bricks)
```

but

```
Box A2 + Box B1 = blue, red, green, yellow (4 unique bricks)
```

So `Box A1 + Box B1` is the better choice.

We need to build a collection of such boxes, choosing at least one version of each box such that the total unique number of bricks is minimum.

Is there a known algorithm to solve this problem?

Comment: This seems to be one of the many variants of the *set covering* problem, which is NP-hard. This would mean that there is not better *correct* algorithm than the obvious "try everything and compare".  There may be incorrect, e.g. approximate algorithms which improve on this bound.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments this problem can be seen as a Set Covering Problem. If you are interested by the optimal solution you can solve it using a Mixed Integer Programming (MIP) solver. For Open source solver you can give a look at glpk or cbc. If you are interested in proprietary solver you can give a look at Cplex, Gurobi or XPress-MP.

You could model it in the following way:

- Associate a binary variable to each individual brick of the problem. Your objective function will be to minimise the sum of those positive variable.
- Associate a binary variable to every possible variation of your boxes. For each box add a constraint stating that the sum of the binary variable associated with variation of this box should be equal to one.
- Finally, for every combination of box variation and brick being part of that variation, add a constraint stating that the binary associated with the box variation should be less or equal to the binary variable associated with the brick.